# Lazy loading doesn't create chunk.js in Angular

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, lazy-loading

I have some project and I want to use lazy loading for component. In *app.module.ts* file I removed from import section three record with my routing to different components. In my app-routing.module.ts I created APP_ROUTES like below:

```
const APP_ROUTES : Route[] = [
    { 
            path: '', pathMatch: 'full', 
        redirectTo: 'login'
    },
    { 
        path: 'cars', 
        loadChildren: 'app/cars/cars.module#CarsModule' 
    }
];

@NgModule({
        imports: [
            RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)
        ],
        exports: [
            RouterModule
        ]
})
```

I have a main folder which name is *cars* and I pasted *CarsRoutingModule* from *app.module.ts* like I said before into *cars.module.ts* (section *imports*). I created ROUTES in my cars modul into *cars-routing.module.ts* like below:

```
const CARS_ROUTES : Route[] = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: <any> CarsComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: <any>CarsListComponent
            },
            { 
                path: ':id', 
                component: <any>CarDetailsComponent,
                resolve: { car: CarResolve }
            }
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
        imports: [
            RouterModule.forChild(CARS_ROUTES)
        ],
        exports: [
            RouterModule
        ]
})
```

and I think it's ok. Ok, so I have second module *login.module.ts* where  I pasted LoginRoutingModule from app.module.ts like I said before into *login.module.ts* (section imports). I created ROUTES like below:

```
const LOGIN_ROUTES : Route[] = [
     { 
         path: 'login', 
         component: <any>LoginComponent,
        }
];

@NgModule({
        imports: [
            RouterModule.forChild(LOGIN_ROUTES)
        ],
        exports: [
            RouterModule
        ]
})
```

and it looks good for me too. I compiled my project without errors. I have login screen so it good, but when I completed login and password and I am into dashboard - I don't see anything like chunk.js (into *Sources* tab too) like below:
[image: Debugger screen]

Guess but correct me if I'm wrong - in angular 4+ we don't have chunk.js file? I checked something else. When I don't have lazy loading in my projekt I have more modules on my login site:
[image]

Like we can see on the left side my debugger in ng folder I have: *AppModule*, *CarsModule*, *CoreModule*, *LoginModule*, *SharedModule*.
When I add lazy-loading in the same place like up, I have only *AppModule*, *CoreModule* and  like below:
[image]

So now, can I be sure that my lazy-loading works good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what was wrong. Code is very good but I used *ng serve*. When I used *ng serve --aot*(Ahead-of-Time) and I have cars.module.chunk.js!